# Count Number of ways to reach Nth step using steps of lengths 1,2,3,4,......m.(where m<=n)

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I'm given a number `n` of order 10<sup>5</sup>. I've to find number of ways to reach n<sup>th</sup> step from ground using steps of length `1 or 2 or 3 or.....or m`, here m<=n.

As the answer can be too large output it modulo **10<sup>9</sup>+7**.

```
#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;

#define ll long long
#define MOD 1000000007

ll countWays_(ll n, ll m){
    ll res[n];
    res[0] = 1; res[1] = 1;
    for (ll i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
       res[i] = 0;
       for (ll j=1; j<=m && j<=i; j++)
         res[i] =(res[i]%MOD+ res[i-j]%MOD)%MOD;
    }
    return res[n-1];
}

ll countWays(ll s, ll m){
    return countWays_(s+1, m);
}
int main (){
    scanf("%lld%lld",&s,&m);
    printf("%lld\n",countWays(s,m));
    return 0;
}
```

As the complexity `O(m*n)`, I want to reduce it.

Comment: Don't use that header ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1116364

Comment: thanx @DanielJour!that is really helpful!!

Comment: Hint: Let f(n, m) be the number of sums from {1..m} that add to n. Write a recurrence relation for f.

Comment: OP, are you familiar with dynamic programming?

Comment: i am learning.and i ll be grateful if u suggest something regarding that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inner loop adds `res[i-1] + res[i-2] + ... + res[i-m]` to the result.

Let `s` be the sum of the first `i` elements in `res`. Then you can simply add `s[i-1] - s[i-m-1]` to the result.

```
ll countWays_(ll n, ll m){
    ll res[n];
    res[0] = 1; res[1] = 1;
    s[0] = 1; s[1] = 2;
    for (ll i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
       if (i <= m)
           res[i] = s[i-1] % MOD;
       else
           res[i] = (s[i-1] - s[i - m - 1] + MOD) % MOD; 
       s[i] = (s[i-1] + res[i]) % MOD;
    }
    return res[n-1];
}
```

The new complexity will be `O(n)`. You can even get rid of `s` as an array and use a single variable with a little more bookkeeping.

Comment: it is not giving desired result

Comment: @waza007 I initialized `s[0]` wrong, I see now that it should have been `1`. Is it giving the correct result now?

Comment: and s[1] should be 2.after all thnx @IVlad....u helped me to reduce useless calculations every time!
a big thanx sir

Answer (score 2):

I think use can use a variable Sum to store sum of res form i-m+1 to i like this:

```
ll mod(ll a, ll b){ 
    return (a%b+b)%b; 
}
ll countWays_(ll n, ll m){
    ll res[n],sum;
    res[0] = 1; res[1] = 1;
    sum = res[0] + res[1];
    int head_sum = 0;
    for (ll i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
       if ((i - head_sum) > m) {
            sum=mod((sum- res[head_sum]),MOD);
            head_sum++;
       }  
       res[i] = sum;
       sum = mod((sum% MOD + res[i]% MOD),MOD);
    }
    return res[n-1];
}
```

Comment: srr, i've not tried it yet. for your code: my idea is store all value which you need to for j in a variable. (EX m=10, you need to go to step 100,you can step from 91,92..99 to step 100, i store all res[91], res[92]..res[100] in var sum so f[100] just equal sum)  I see your code, i think your code give the wrong answer because your for from 1 then f[100] = f[1]+...f[10]

Comment: bro i ran my code in a pogramming contest where i have to do it for m==3.
it was accepted there. so knew that i am getting correct result for sample tests i run on my code.and the same test inputs i tried on dat of yours it is giving wrong result!

Comment: I've test this code with your code in some test cases. It may return negative value by %. I've fix it. I hope this new code will be correct

Comment: yes there were negative results due to which it seemed me if the code was wrong.
Thnx bro!